# IndexDB in iframe safari

Tags: javascript, iframe, safari

I try to display a site from an iframe.

It works fine in Windows with chrome,
and stuck in Safari with Mac or IOS.

Main site and iframe are in same subdomain.
I set in two sites `document.domain` to have the same value.

When I call `indexDb.open()` in the Iframe,
I got this error

`SecurityError: IDBFactory.open() called in an invalid security context`

Do I have a possibility to run indexDB from the Iframe?

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Don't think there is a solution to this due to the new "Prevent cross-site tracking" feature in Safari. It seems to work when you disable "Prevent cross-site tracking" in Safari's Preferences > Privacy.

Comment: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2393